# locomotive cms Assets missing from backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, nitrousio, locomotivecms

I know It's better to use this cms on a Virtual machine, with some OS like linux, etc. (because this command: `$ wagon serve` doesn't run on windows at all)
I decided to use nitrous io and it's working really good (on a ubuntu os) the only problem is when I do the Preview of my locomotive cms installation it shows the backend without the styles (css).

Rails 3.2.19
 ruby 2.1.0

Here  step by step commands I ran, that didn't work for me:
First, my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '3.2.19'
gem 'locomotive_cms', '~> 2.4.1', :require => 'locomotive/engine'
group :assets do
  gem 'compass',        '~> 0.12.7'
gem 'compass-rails',  '~> 1.0.2'
  gem 'sass-rails',     '~> 3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails',   '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',       '~> 2.5.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
end
# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'rake', '10.0.4'
```

As suggested in the locomotivecms documentation, I started creating a new rails project for the engine:

```
$ rails new codigos_comentados_engine --skip-active-record --skip-test-unit --skip-javascript --skip-bundle

$ bundle
```

Creating the locomotivecms engine:

```
$  rails generate locomotive:install
```

Then, some files in the project didn't work in environment/production.rb and  environment/development.rb:

```
Error: undefined method `configure' for #<CodigosComentadosEngine::Application:0x007f8
03fe43bf0> (NoMethodError)
```

Solved when changing this:

```
Rails.Aplication.configure do
```

by this:

```
CodigosComentadosEngine::Application.configure do
```

Then, locomotive engine worked well and I got this nice output :

```
  1. blah blah
  2. bundle exec unicorn_rails
  3. Open your browser                                 
     open localhost:8080                                            
  4. Follow the installation wizard steps                                     
  5. Enjoy !
```

Then:

```
$ bundle exec unicorn_rails
```

I got this warning  But the server was working anyway:

```
WARNING: unable to load the content types, Could not connect to any secondary or primary nodes for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:270
17">]>
```

OK. when I opened this url in my browser: myprojectblahblahblah.nitrousbox.com:8080

I got the next message:

```
ArgumentError: A secret is required to generate an integrity hash for cookie session data. Use config.secret_token = "some secret phrase of at least 30 characters"in config/initializers/secret_token.rb
```

Ok. I created the secret token file in config/initializers/secret_token.rb

```
CodigosComentadosEngine::Application.config.secret_token = 'blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah'
```

Installing mongodb according to nitrous help docs:

```
 $ parts install mongodb
```

Starting mongodb:

```
 $ parts start mongodb
 ok. => Started: mongodb
```

Starting server unicorn again:

```
 $ bundle exec unicorn_rails
```

**everything alright.**
 ...

Preview in the browser:  myprojectblahblahblah.nitrousbox.com:8080

**BUT The styles of the backend doesn't appear, loads everthing, without the styles I could even create an user and see my site.**

When I inspected the html the path of the `<script></script>` in the head was:

```
myprojectblahblah.nitrousbox.com:8080/javascripts/locomotive/not_logged_in.js
myprojectblahblah.nitrousbox.com:8080/stylesheets/locomotive/not_logged_in.css
```

---

In a forum I found this step by step that worked for them, not for me on nitrous with ubuntu: 
link [https://locomotivecms.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/309-backend-themestyles-does-not-apply-missing-files-reopen#comment_31593155][1]

To make the public/assets directory "appears"  in the link was suggested to run this command:

```
 $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

After running this command, I got this output:

```
 Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest                   
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/bin/ruby /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets                          
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
```

But puplic/assets was not appearing in the directory, and not showing any style in the backend of locomotive (the forms, and web is loading)

After that, I ran the same command but with --trace, and i got the following output:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile
```

OUTPUT:

```
    rake aborted!            
    Don't know how to build task 'default'  
    /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:142:in `invoke_task'
    ...
   /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top  (required)>' 
    /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'  
    /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I google "rake aborted!   Don't know how to build task 'default'" and I noticed that in the Rakefile i had this line:

```
 `Rails.application.load_tasks`
```

and I changed by:

```
CodigosComentadosEngine::Application.load_tasks
```

I added this line in GemFile: gem rake '10.0.4'

Then I ran this command with a successful output: (both RAILS_ENV=development and RAILS_ENV=production return a successful output)

```
 $ RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile
```

Output:

```
 /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/bin/ruby /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=development RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace                 
Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest                       
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)                    
** Execute assets:precompile:all                               
**.....                          
** Execute assets:precompile:primary  
....
```

After that, (according to the forum link I posted) the idea was that you MUST to see the public/assets directory, but I don't see it. The weird thing is that when I installed it on Windows (7) the backend styles loaded perfect, the problem there was the `$wagon serve command`, that was a known win issue.

I'm going to try in a ubuntu locally, without nitrous. I'll update this question if I have success. Have you got a similar issue with this cms and **nitrous**?

PS. Sorry My English maybe is not perfect. Thanks for any help!

Comment: While you have shown some of the steps taken already, it would be worth adding details on the 'some commands' people told you to run so that you don't get the same suggestions, as well as giving more insight into what the problem might actually be.

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna write the step by step I did.

Comment: I tried this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562239/locomotivecms-assets-in-production didn't work for me. I dont know if I did something wrong but at least i tried.

Comment: @melipip were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I spent some time trying to make it works on Windows (and nitrous), without good results. Finally the locomotiveCMS support told me better to move to linux or os x.  Windows is not a good choice for RoR related technologies. Cheers!